# scan PDF417 from codenameone android

Tags: codenameone

I use codename one to do some app development.
The Codename java scanner cant scan PDF417.  I need a driver/library that can scan pdf417 that I can use in codenameone. Can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

Just the other day one of our subscribers indicated you can change this line in the cn1lib https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-codescan/blob/master/native/android/com/codename1/ext/codescan/NativeCodeScannerImpl.java#L22

To:

```
if(!in.initiateScan(types, "PDF_417")){​ ... }
```

You can do that and recompile the library to replace your local cn1lib.

Comment: What if I need to maintain the old codes can cn1 lib in my project because I need to scan QR Codes too?  How to add this new Scan for PDF without losing the old feature and without having any conflicts of names related to the old lib that must be present in parallel;

Comment: You can pass any of the types you want there dynamically. You can also ignore the types altogether to try and scan for everything. Most libraries don't support arbitrary QR/barcode modes so you need to pick one or the other.