# I would like to read PDF417 bar codes

Tags: codenameone, pdf417

I need to read a PDF417 barcode.

The following code, however, causes my app to open a dialog which asks to Install Barcode Scanner" when running on my Android phone.

The dialog gives me options to install a "BARCODE SCANNER" and to install "BARCODE SCANNER + SIMPLE".

The "BARCODE SCANNER" option installs an app on the phone (via the PlayStore).
The "BARCODE SCANNER + SIMPLE" option takes me to a page in the PlayStore that says "Something went wrong".

After installing the app on the first option, clicking the button in my app displays the same dialog asking to install the application.

```
    private void scanDisk() {
        CodeScanner scanner = CodeScanner.getInstance();

        if (scanner == null) {
            CodenameOneUtils.toastMessage("Scanner is null");
            return;
        }

        scanner.scanQRCode(new ScanResult() {
            @Override
            public void scanCompleted(String s, String s1, byte[] bytes) {
                CodenameOneUtils.showDialog(s + "/n" + s1);
            }

            @Override
            public void scanCanceled() {
                // nothing - do we care?
            }

            @Override
            public void scanError(int i, String s) {
                // we should really show a message...
                CodenameOneUtils.toastMessage("Scan failed: " + s);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you're using [this version of the QRScanner depenedency](https://github.com/codenameone/QRScanner). The older code scanner approach was broken by Android 13.

Comment: I used the version as indicated, I had to change the dependency to get mine to compile and work.

I had to change the artifact from qrscanner-lib to qrscanner-common in order to compile it.

Comment: It is with this library that I keep getting the "Install Barcode Scanner" dialog.


`        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codenameone</groupId>
            <artifactId>qrscanner-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
`

Comment: You should use lib as indicated in the instructions. The question is why didn't it compile with lib?

Comment: It does compile and run in the simulator with the -lib dependency.

The jar file, however doesnt show up in my .m2 repostitory.  Don't know if that means anything.

Adding it as -common allowed me to create a build, but caused the issue as mentioned above.

I, however, cannot test this on the simulator because scanning isn't supported there.  The build of even a simple app with scanning functionality fails because of the filesize limit.

I need to prove that I can scan PDF 417 images.

Comment: Right, that's a problem of the newer API. Unfortunately, there isn't much we can do. Android 13 broke all the legacy QR code support so the only solution is to embed a native scanner into the app. That's what the lib extension does. The native scanner is much larger so it does go over the limit which is something we hadn't considered but I don't think there's a workaround.

Comment: So how can I be sure that I can scan PDF417 codes with CodenameOne before we spend money on the CodenameOne licences? 

I can provide a small app that simply scans a PDF417 code and shows the information contained in the barcode.

Comment: I think your only choice on Android would be a local build using the maven native targets. That's a bit of a pain though.

Comment: I built the app locally and installed the APK on my phone.  When the scan button is clicked I see a dialog that says: "Install Barcode scanner?", "This application require Barcode Scanner. Would you like to install it?" with a "No" and "Yes" button.

If I click "Yes" I get taken to a Google Play page that says "Something went wrong" with a "try again" option.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the lib dependency here? This seems to be fallback code that's missing the native portion of the code. Does the generated project include `ZBarScannerLibrary.aar`? Can you look at the device logcat when running the application?

Comment: I am using the lib, yes.

`
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codenameone</groupId>
            <artifactId>qrscanner-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
`

(this is in the POM file in the common directory.

How would I see the .aar file?

Comment: The aar file should be in the resulting native project that you compile with xcode. The functionality you're seeing seems to be fallback functionality which happens if the native code fails.

Comment: I'm not compiling with xCode - I'm compiling Android.

I do see the file ZBarScannerLibrary.aar in C:\Users\Tony\intellij\workspace\myapp\android\target\codenameone\antProject\dist\android-build\MyApp\app\libs

Comment: Sorry, I meant Android Studio. Do you see anything in the console? You should see something such as a failure to load of the code and fallback functionality. Is that happening?

Comment: The only questionable things in the logs are (1/2):
`
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug, :app:assembleDebugUnitTest, :app:assembleDebugAndroidTest] in project C:\...\target\myapp-android-1.0-SNAPSHOT-android-source

AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"The option setting 'android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true' is deprecated.\nThe current default is 'false'.\nIt will be removed in version 9.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.\nYou can resolve this warning in Android Studio via `Refactor` > `Migrate BuildConfig to Gradle Build Files`","sources":[{}]}
`

Comment: (2/2)
`
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"DSL element 'dexOptions' is obsolete and should be removed.\nIt will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.\nUsing it has no effect, and the AndroidGradle plugin optimizes dexing automatically.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Using flatDir should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.","sources":[{}]}

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
`

Comment: I meant the runtime log when you try to launch the scanning. You can look at the device output in logcat and you might see an exception or some other reason why the scanning is failing. You can also debug the code in Android Studio by finding [this file](https://github.com/codenameone/QRScanner/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/codename1/ext/codescan/NativeCodeScannerImpl.java#L32) in the project and placing a breakpoint there. Then just follow the logic of the library to see what's going on.

Comment: There are these warnings:

Comment: [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example.myapp:myapp-javase:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.codenameone:codenameone-core:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 60, column 19
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.codenameone:codenameone-javase:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 70, column 19

Comment: [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.

Comment: Apart from this there is nothing else that is related to scanning.  Obviously I cannot test it in the simulator.

in the simulator:

`CodeScanner scanner = CodeScanner.getInstance();`

leaves scanner as null.

Comment: These are build problems... I'm talking about runtime problems. Connect the physical device with a cable to Android Studio and debug on the device from the IDE.

Comment: The only errors in logcat are:

WorkSourceUtil    com.google.android.gms E Could not find package: com.example.myapp
SPPClientServiceS com.sec.spp.push       E [PackageRemoveReceiver] [handlePkgRemovedEvent] PackageName : com.example.myapp
VerityUtils       system_server          E Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 25: /data/app/~~wSpSBpMEGutmCZsTH5-1dg==/com.example.myapp-O_I4V0tAaZHqYfrSLllATg==/base.apk

Comment: ...continue

WindowManager     system_server          E win=Window{27a9fd u0 com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MyAppStub} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true cleanupOnResume=false
WindowManager     system_server          E win=Window{27a9fd u0 com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MyAppStub} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true cleanupOnResume=false

Comment: I don't see why this would be failing but can you try placing a breakpoint in the debugger and stepping over when it's running on the device? It would help track this much faster.

Comment: On stepping over the `scanner.scanBarCode(new ScanResult() {...` code I see the following:

2024-01-11 09:00:41.647 12744-12744 ViewRootIm...MyAppStub] com.example.myapp                    I  ViewPostIme pointer 0
2024-01-11 09:00:41.681 12744-12744 ViewRootIm...MyAppStub] com.example.myapp                    I  ViewPostIme pointer 1
2024-01-11 09:00:43.196 12744-12744 ViewRootIm...MyAppStub] com.example.myapp                    I  ViewPostIme pointer 0
2024-01-11 09:00:43.765 12744-12744 ViewRootIm...MyAppStub] com.example.myapp                    I  ViewPostIme pointer 1

Comment: The dialog then pops up asking me to "Install Barcode Scanner?".

Comment: The ZXing Team Barcode Scanner is already installed, but the phone then opens the Playstore showing the installed application.

Comment: It's possible I'm a total idiot and sent you down a wrong path. Can you make sure that you're using `org.littlemonkey.qrscanner.QRScanner` and not `CodeScanner`?

Comment: AH!!!!  This made a world of a difference!

I can scan "normal" barcodes now.  I still cannot, however, scan PDF417 barcodes, which is my requirement.

Comment: Sorry about that... It's always the simplest things. I posted an answer to this, I hope it's the right one this time.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Display.getInstance().putProperty("scanAllCodeTypes", "true")` to the `init(Object)` callback in your main class. This should force scanning for any type of QR/bar code as seen from [this code](https://github.com/codenameone/QRScanner/blob/master/android/src/main/java/org/littlemonkey/qrscanner/NativeScannerImpl.java#L30).

If this doesn't work or isn't efficient we might need to do something more aggressive.

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean.  Here is my code at the present:

` Display.getInstance().setProperty("android.scanTypes", "PDF_417");`
`        Display.getInstance().setProperty("scanAllCodeTypes", "true");`

`        QRScanner.scanBarCode(new ScanResult() {`
`...`
`        });`

Comment: I assume that adding this additional property still doesn't solve the problem? In that case we might need to add a bigger gun. In the native project find [this code](https://github.com/codenameone/QRScanner/blob/master/android/src/main/java/org/littlemonkey/qrscanner/NativeScannerImpl.java#L30C41-L30C41) remove the if statement just for testing. Then replace the `putExtra` with `intent.putExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_MODES, new int[]{Symbol.PDF417});`.

Comment: No, its still not working.  I can scan regular barcodes, but not PDF417.

This class is is in the library that's imported, how should I change it? The project also does not directly use NativeScannerImpl, so I cannot create a new class and call that instead.

Comment: I found that I could edit the NativeScannerImpl class in Android Studio, I added the lines:

`Log.p(">>>> Adding PDF417 support!!");`
`intent.putExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_MODES, new int[]{Symbol.PDF417});`

and I commented the IF out.  When running on the device I can see the Log message in the LogCat as the app runs.

This, however, still doesnt allow me to scan PDF417 barcodes.

Comment: If you're sure you did that correctly and that our code doesn't replace the`putExtra` that you added then I'm afraid we're out of luck. It probably means the support for PDF147 wasn't added to the native library.  That probably means recompiling that library with this support in place. I haven't done this, it's a library that the guys at LittleMonkey compiled so I can't guide you on that process.

Comment: If I use this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438956/scan-pdf417-from-codenameone-android), and use the library at [link](https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-codescan/tree/master) and rebuild then cn1 lib would that work for PDF417?

Comment: No. That worked for the old approach of launching an external activity to perform the task. Android 13 essentially broke that functionality for all apps. It made a lot of things much harder.

Comment: ah, yes you mentioned android 13... 

So basically, you're saying that CodenameOne cannot scan PDF 417 barcodes at this time?

Comment: It seems that this is indeed the case. The workaround is probably to recompile the native library with PDF417 support enabled but it's not something we did as the people at littlemonkey did that. I think they mostly cared about QR code working so they probably didn't notice that.